# Accessing shell through julia REPL doesnot work in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

When I access the shell through julia REPL (`;`), most of the shell functions are not working. Any idea how how to fix this?

The error I get is `zsh:1: command not found: mkdir`

Note this behaviour is only when I access the shell through julia REPL using vscode. Within the regular macos terminal everything works fine. So I have feeling I messed up the vscode settings.json file.

```
shell> mkdir julia
zsh:1: command not found: mkdir

shell> ls
zsh:1: command not found: ls

shell> pwd
/Users/imantha/workspace/coursera/devoping_the_sir_model
```

Comment: 1) Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) 2) what shell is this?

Comment: What OS are you using? I tried VS-Code (1.79.2) on Linux (Debian 12) with the extension julialang (1.47.2) and installed Julia (1.9.1) using juliaup. Where `ls`, `pwd` or `mkdir` works using the shell from Julia in VS-Code. In my case `bash` is used as shell (using `ps` in the shell to see it).

Comment: I am using mac, os x. And I am using z-shell which I think is default in macs

Comment: Do you have this only in VS-Code or also when using Julia REPL direct?

Comment: Yes its only a vscode thing. It works fine when I open a julia REPL from the terminal and then use the shell using ]. I think its something to with the vscode settings.json file but cant say with certainty.